# Why ConcurrentModificationException in ArrayList?

Tags: java, collections

why following code throwing ConcurrentModificationException? Josh Bloch can avoid ConcurrentModificationException.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(100);
list.add(200);
list.add(300);
list.add(400);
for(Integer field : list) {    
    list.remove(field);
    list.add(200);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use remove on the list while using the "for each" loop.  Instead, you can use this to call remove on the iterator:

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer integer = iterator.next();

    // ...check if you want to remove this one...

    iterator.remove();
}
```

If you actually want to replace every value with "200", or replace with some other value, it might make more sense to build up a new list:

```
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer integer = iterator.next();

    newList.add(integer);

    iterator.remove();
}
```

Comment: you can't add either ...

Comment: good to know the for-each limitation in this case.

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear what the behavior should be if you're iterating over an array while modifying it.

What if you remove an element, should it still be iterated over?

Rather than trying to guess, the list throws a ConcurrentModificationException to cause an error rather than pass with unexpected behavior.

One solution is that you could iterate over a shallow copy of the list, and then modify the original list

Answer (score 0):

You can remove objects from the ArrayList which you are using. I use this in my game engine and it works.

See http://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/source/browse/src/com/gej/map/Map.java#350

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
    GObject other = objects.get(i);
    if (other.isAlive()) {
        // Update it
    } else {
        // Else remove it
        objects.remove(i);
    }
}
```

What the error you are having is this does not work for the `for each` loop. Try in a normal `for` loop and that should solve your problem.

Change your code to this.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list =new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> remove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(100);
list.add(200);
list.add(300);
list.add(400);
// Mark to remove
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
    remove.add(list.get(i));
}
list.removeAll(remove);
remove.clear();
// adding 200 at the end because if added in the loop,
// it removes the 200 and adds every loop which causes
// unnecessary memory usage.
list.add(200);
```

Comment: You will miss elements in the for-loop, because the index value (`i`) is increasing while your list size is decreasing through removal.

Comment: The loop above has this issue, too.

Comment: Try compiling it. It's working.

Comment: I don't mean compiler errors. Assume you have this list `[a, b, c]`. You remove the element at `i = 0`: The list is now `[b, c]`. In the second iteration `i` is incremented to 1, so you will miss the element `b` in the list, which is after the deletion at index 0.

Comment: I had even run it. See the code. I was marking the elements to be removed by adding them to another list and removing them. This is 100% working.

Comment: No, I mean the code from the game engine above.